# Set TitledPane height in JavaFX

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, menu, accordion

I have a JavaFX application using gradle. I have used an `Accordion` as container for my `TitledPane` for my menu. The problem is that I can't set the `TitledPane` height according to sum of it's content height.
For example `TitledPane` 1 has 3 button inside:

[image]

So I set the height manually. But for `TitledPane` 2 I need to set height exactly for 1 button and remove extra blank spaces:

[image]

How could I do that? By the way the button border of `Accordion` gets disappear when I expand any `TitledPane`. My tress structure of `Accordion` is:

[image]

I have tried using css like:

```
.accordion .titled-pane {
    -fx-fit-to-height: true;
}
```

or:

```
.accordion .titled-pane {
     -fx-fit-to-height: true;
}
```

or some other css codes.

Comment: Please post [mre]

Comment: @c0der thanks for the response, It doesn't have and need java codes. I make the `Accordion` using Scene Builder and `fxml` codes. It is the tree structure shown in image

Comment: When you're using SceneBuilder just set your parent min_height and width to computed, then the pref_height and width to computed and max_height and width to pref. This should probably fix it because it worked for me well.

Comment: @fuggerjaki61Thanks my friend. Your solution was the answer.

Comment: It's functionality is great now. but there is still an issue that bottom border get's dis-appeared when I open any `TitledPane`. As you see in the images black border is gone in bottom of the menu